# why ndk-build.cmd tries to create or access to a folder named "."?

Tags: java, android-ndk, telegram

I am trying to compile/open downloaded Telegram messenger source code in Android Studio and i get this error:

```
Error while executing process \android-ndk-r13b\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=\Telegram1\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=e:\Telegram1\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=/Telegram1/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=e:\Telegram1\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\foss\lib NDK_PROJECT_PATH:=e:/Telegram1/TMessagesProj NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 ANDROID_DEPRECATED_HEADERS=true APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
```

I understand this problem is related to ndk, and when i'm trying to make/build Telegram's "jni" folder with calling ndk-build.cmd in the tmessageproj subfolder of telegram project's main folder like this:

```
e:\telegram1\tmessageproj\e:\android-ndk-r13b\ndk-build.cmd
```

i get this error:

```
No rule to make target jni/./libtgvoip/client/android/tg_void_jni.cpp' needed by 
'obj/local/armeabi/objs/tmessages.27/./libtgvoip/client/android/tg_void_jni.o'
```

And in the head of android.mk file i have this code:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

I think this error occurs when ndk tries to create a folder with name '.' and windows OS do not lets. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Windows has no problem understanding that `jni/.` is the same directory as `jni`, so that shouldn't be the problem. You should add your makefiles to your question. Also, `e:\telegram1\tmessageproj\e:\android-ndk-r13b\ndk-build.cmd` looks really weird. Why is there a second `e:` in the middle of that string? Also, why is `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` referring to a different disk volume (`D:`)?

Comment: @Michael thank you for comment,1- in "e:\telegram1\tmessageproj\e:\android-ndk-r13b\ndk-build.cmd" the "e:\android-ndk-r13b\ndk-build.cmd" is to calling ndk-build.cmd, as you know if we are in a directory, when we want to call a file in the other folder(out of current folder path) we must refer with full path.
2- I edited this "NDK_PROJECT_PATH" in question. i changed all of D: to e: manually, this is no problem.